# Initializing a 2D array of pointers as a member variable in C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, dynamic-arrays

I've been searching around Stack Overflow and the cplusplus forums with no luck. I am new to c++ and I'm currently working on a game for a school project. I have no problem creating, filling, destroying a 2d array of pointers and was using one in my game and it was working great.

I created a new class for a player and moved the 2d array into that class. Now when I try to run my program I get a segmentation fault. Can anyone give me some insight into why this is happening? *bold I can't simply use a `std::vector<>` because the 2d array of pointers is a requirement.*

```
class Player
{
public:
  Player();
  ...
  short** allocate_2d_array();
  ....
protected:
  short **board;
  static const short BOARD_DIMENSIONS;
  ...
};
```

The function

```
short** Player::allocate_2d_array()
{
  short **array2d;

  // Insert columns
  for(int i = 0; i < this->BOARD_DIMENSIONS; i++)
  {
    array2d[i] = new short[this->BOARD_DIMENSIONS];
    // Fill in the numbers
    for(int j = 0; j < this->BOARD_DIMENSIONS; j++)
    {
      array2d[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }

  return array2d;
}
```

Where it's called

```
Player::Player()
{
  this->turns_taken = 0;
  // Prepare the board
  this->board = this->allocate_2d_array();
  ...
}
```

Comment: may be you can use :vector< vector<short> > board(BOARD_DIMENSIONS,vector<short>(BOARD_DIMENSIONS,0)); to replace allocate_2d_array

Comment: Also I'm not sure why you would want `allocate_2d_array` to be publicly accessible

Comment: It shouldn't be public, copy and paste error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line of the body of your for loop dereferences the pointer `array2d` (using the square bracket operator) before you've allocated any memory for it, or initialized it.

To avoid this issue, you'll have to allocate the first dimension of your array before entering your for loop. Once you've allocated this array of pointers, you can then allocate `BOARD_DIMENSIONS` arrays of `short`s and store the pointers to them in the elements of the first array.

Something like:

```
short** array2d = new short*[BOARD_DIMENSIONS];
for (size_t u = 0; u < BOARD_DIMENSIONS; ++u)
{
    array2d[u] = new short[BOARD_DIMENSIONS];
    // You could then use memset to initialize the array, or
    // use a for loop, like in your example:
    for (size_t v = 0; v < BOARD_DIMENSIONS; ++v)
    {
        array2d[u][v] = 0;
    }
 }
```

Make sure when you're done with the memory that you release it properly, using `operator delete []`

Comment: Argh! Text book amateur mistake... Thanks!

Comment: YW. And as others have noted, if this wasn't homework, you'd likely be better served using one or two STL data containers.

Comment: Thus works unless I'm creating a pointer to the Person class. For example Person somedude; works fine but. Person somedude = new Person; still generates a segmentation fault.

Comment: `Person somedude` is an instance of a `Person`; you want a pointer. Try `Person* pSomedude = new Person`.

Comment: That's what I had, it compiles, but that causes a segmentation fault when I try to use the above function.

Comment: I ran this code and didn't have any issues. Did you find your problem? Also, no need to return the pointer from a private member function - you can set the member variable right in the function.